# React Native "Module not Found" for Images

Tags: react-native, expo

Apologies if this is a stupid question -- I'm learning React Native with Expo Go, and I'm pulling images from an assets folder with the following structure:

```
assets/
    image folder 1
    image folder 2
    ...
    index.js
```

Index.js is as follows:

```
const Images = {
  1: {
    // bb
    0: require("./bb/0.JPG"),
  },
  2: {
    // sb
    0: require("./sb/0.JPG"),
    1: require("./sb/1.JPG"),
    2: require("./sb/2.JPG"),
  },
  3: {
    // btn
    0: require("./btn/0.JPG"),
    1: require("./btn/1.JPG"),
    2: require("./btn/2.JPG"),
  },
  4: {
    // co
    0: require("./co/0.JPG"),
    1: require("./co/1.JPG"),
    2: require("./co/2.JPG"),
  },
  5: {
    // hj
    0: require("./hj/0.JPG"),
    1: require("./hj/1.JPG"),
    2: require("./hj/2.JPG"),
  },
  6: {
    // lj
    0: require("./lj/0.JPG"),
    1: require("./lj/1.JPG"),
    2: require("./lj/2.JPG"),
  },
  7: {
    // utg2
    0: require("./utg2/0.JPG"),
    1: require("./utg2/1.JPG"),
    2: require("./utg2/2.JPG"),
  },
  8: {
    // utg1
    0: require("./utg1/0.jpg"),
    1: require("./utg1/1.JPG"),
    2: require("./utg1/2.JPG"),
  },
  9: {
    // utg
    0: require("./utg/0.jpg"),
    1: require("./utg/1.jpg"),
  },
};

export default Images;
```

In my app.js, I have this line:
`import Images from "./assets/index.js";`

This project works fine as an Expo snack, but when I tried downloading it and running it with Expo Go, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./bb/0.JPG from (Project Directory)\assets\index.js: 

None of these files exist:
  * assets\bb\0.JPG(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)
  * assets\bb\0.JPG\index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.cjs|.native.cjs|.cjs)
```

I double checked and the files are present, so I'm not exactly sure what I could be doing wrong here. I tried removing the `require`s and it obviously broke, and don't know exactly what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

File systems are case-sensitive when it comes to file extensions.

Could you confirm if the correct extension is .JPG or .jpg?

Comment: Yes, all of the extensions are correct. I figured out that the issue is that all extensions must be lowercase for some reason.